# Why I cannot receive `Access Token` from OAuth 2 server as JSON and I need to define `redirect_uri`?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, okta, okta-api

I am trying to get JWT `Access Token` from `Okta API` which is using standard `OAuth 2` flow except for using `sessionToken` so I am able to use my own custom login form and not redirection to their login page.

I need this JWT to access API in my automated tests so I am doing whole OAuth 2 login flow in Java.

What I do:

- I am sending username/password to `/api/v1/authn` and I get `sessionToken` in response
- Using this `sessionToken` in `/oauth2/default/v1/token` to receive my JWT

I see problem in second part of this workflow, because I need to pass `redirect_uri` as parameter even I am not on client and I want to receive JWT right in response to use it in my Java project's API calls.

Is there a way in standard OAuth2 to get the Token without need to return it on `redirect_uri` or it is just the way OAuth2 works, that you can receive token only on defined endpoints...

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not, unfortunately, unless you want to do `client_credentials` flow instead. All other flows assume that they are executed by a user's agent, hence there should be a redirect to some app page with the information payload (code or tokens) from the authZ server.

But how does it stop you from obtaining a token? You can just ignore redirecting and process the response from your authorization server. You can check the snippet I posted in https://devforum.okta.com/t/list-users-and-groups-with-and-administrator-read-only-account-with-no-login-page-prompted/15925/5?u=phi1ipp to implement a similar solution